I forgot the answer to my cryptic clue: Country road endlessly weaves through top of Iowa (7)
I was looking back through my notes app and found a cryptic clue I wrote during a long car ride. I'm fairly new to cryptics (solving or setting), but I remember being fairly proud of how smooth the surface reading is. However, I don't remember the solution, and coming back to it I can't figure it out, and it's bugging me. The clue is,

Country road endlessly weaves through top of Iowa (7)

I do have some fuzzy memory w.r.t. what different portions of the clue mean, but I figure I'll let y'all take a stab first and post those as hints later (if needed).
Edit:
First answer (deleted) got me thinking down a different line, and I remembered the solution. Turns out past me is dumb, because the answer is definitely 7 letters, not 6. I still don't entirely understand the wordplay, which may or may not be another dumb by past me.

I think it may be

 Romania

Reasoning

 Country is the definition.
 "Road endlessly" is ROA.
 Then I think "top of Iowa" is doing two jobs representing Minnesota (MN), the state directly to the north of ("top of") Iowa and Iowa itself (IA).
 Weaving ROA through MN and adding IA gives ROMANIA.


You're right that rot13(gur bqq ovg nobhg gur jbeqcynl vf Vbjn cynlvat qbhoyr qhgl). I'm not sure that your solution is less valid than the intended solution, but still isn't quite right

@ash4fun My other idea was rot13(PEBNGVN) with a similar idea although I couldn't get that to work as cleanly

That's not it either
